# Simplify $L_2$ norm

Tags: linear-algebra

What types of simplifications are there when you have $||x-y||^2$?, where $x$ and $y$ are both dimension $d$ vectors and $||\;||$ denotes the $L_2$ norm. I am having difficulty simplifying or rewriting this in other terms.

Comment: You need to elaborate a little more. One can write $\|x-y\|^2 = \langle x-y, x-y \rangle$ and expand using linearity.

Comment: If $x = (x_1,\ldots x_d)$ and $y = (y_1,\ldots y_d)$, then $\|x-y\|^2 = \sum_{j=1}^d (x_j - y_j)^2$, which should be straightforward to differentiate with respect to any of the $x_j$ or $y_j$.

Comment: Well the goal here was to leave it in vector form. Lets say I expand the ( x - y)^2. Take derivates, I'll be left with something like summation 2yj - 2xj, how would I rewrite this back into vector form? I saw your earlier solution of something like ||x||^2 ... which seemed like where I should head.

Comment: Taking the partial derivative of the sum with respect to $y_j$ would give you $-2(x_j - y_j)$, and stacking these into a vector would give you $-2(x-y) = 2(y-x)$.

Comment: Have you heard of the least squares problem? I'm trying to figure out how 1/2 ||t-Xw||^2 l2 norm can be rewritten as 1/2 ||t||^2 + 1/2 (w^T X^T X w) - t^T Xw

Comment: @Lily I recommend adding these details to the question itself. I assume your vectors are real, in which case $\langle x,y \rangle = x^T y = y^T x = \langle y,x \rangle$. In that case, $\|t - Xw\|^2 = \langle t - Xw, t - Xw \rangle =  \langle t,t\rangle - \langle t, Xw\rangle - \langle Xw, t \rangle + \langle Xw, Xw \rangle = \|t\|^2 - 2\langle t, Xw\rangle + \langle Xw, Xw \rangle = \|t\|^2 - 2 t^T Xw + (Xw)^T (Xw) = \|t\|^2 - 2t^T Xw + w^T X^T X w$.

Comment: Read my comment above. $\|x-y\|^2 = \|x\|^2 + 2 \langle x , y \rangle + \|y\|^2$. Now let $x=t, y=Xw$ and expand.

Comment: @copper.hat Second term should have a minus sign.

Comment: @Bungo: You are right, of course. I'm too lazy to retype my comment :-(.